# Why does slots not work with final dataclass attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a dataclass with `slots=True` and a final class variable/constant that is used as version identifier. For some reason that does not work as expected. I either need to remove the slots or change `Final` to `ClassVar`.

Here is a minimal example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Final, ClassVar

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Child():
    VERSION: Final[str] = '1.0.0'

    @classmethod
    def check_version(cls, version: str) -> bool:
        return version == cls.VERSION

print(Child.check_version('1.0.0'))
# Returns False
```

Could anyone explain me why this happens and how to fix it properly? I am using python 3.11.7

Comment: Hmm... mypy doesn't like it if you try to apply both `ClassVar` and `Final` in the same annotation. I'm not sure if there's actually a way to handle this from your end. It'd probably need changes in the `dataclasses` and/or mypy tooling.

Comment: I also read that combining Final and ClassVar is an option, but is this a valid syntax? how to find out?

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered a bug in the CPython implementation of dataclasses.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest runtime fix is to do the following:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t
from dataclasses import dataclass

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import Final
else:
    from typing import ClassVar as Final

@dataclass(slots=True)
class Child:
    VERSION: Final[str] = "1.0.0"

    @classmethod
    def check_version(cls, version: str) -> bool:
        return version == cls.VERSION
```

```
>>> print(Child.check_version("1.0.0"))
True
```

---

`typing.Final` is a stricter version of `typing.ClassVar`, indicating to type-checkers that a class variable cannot be overridden. From [PEP 591](https://peps.python.org/pep-0591/#semantics-and-examples):

> Type checkers should infer a final attribute that is initialized in a class body as being a class variable. Variables should not be annotated with both `ClassVar` and `Final`.

As part of `@dataclasses.dataclass`'s magic determination of instance variables (as opposed to class variables) when it makes its constructor method (`__init__`), it does runtime introspection to exclude `typing.ClassVar`-annotated variables. Unfortunately, as of today, the [introspection procedure doesn't consider `typing.Final`-annotated variables](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/baae73d7307214ee97abbe80aaa8c1c773a6f682/Lib/dataclasses.py#L796-L818), which looks like an implementation bug.

If you're using mypy - unfortunately, mypy also doesn't pick up that `Final` indicates a class variable and not an instance variable when using `@dataclasses.dataclass(slots=True)`, which is also a bug:

```py
@dataclass(slots=True)
class Child:
    VERSION: Final[str] = "1.0.0"

    @classmethod
    def check_version(cls, version: str) -> bool:
        return version == cls.VERSION  # mypy: "VERSION" in __slots__ conflicts with class variable access  [misc]
```

Comment: Thanks. If that is a python bug, did you report it somewhere? As this is very specific I would not really know how to explain the bug. You seem to be a very experienced python core developer.

Comment: @NicoHood I am not a Python core developer, and I didn't report the bug. You can simply post an issue on https://github.com/python/cpython/issues, title it *Slots does not work with `typing.Final` dataclass attribute*, then explain that you expected `typing.Final` to work like `typing.ClassVar` in the body of a dataclass using the example you have in this question, and that it doesn't work as expected. Put a link to this question if need be.

Comment: Alright, here is the bug report: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/115879

Comment: It looks like some people have started using `typing.Final` to mean what is essentially `dataclass(frozen=True)` but for specific fields (instead of all fields). Admittedly, there's no workaround for freezing specific fields in the standard library, but personally, I'm not very sympathetic to this usage of `Final`; I don't consider it intuitive at all, it's ignoring what was clearly laid out in PEP 591, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Final) don't specify any behaviour for instances, and you now can't specify `Final` class variables without a hacky workaround.

Comment: To be honest, rather than having `typing.Final` mean something to instance variables (which doesn't even work at runtime for preventing instance variable reassignment anyway), the fix in the standard library should be to allow `dataclasses.field(frozen=True)`, where such a field would generate a frozen [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) instead.

Comment: ...or even simpler, modify the `__setattr__` generated to look at a container of field names which was initialised with `dataclasses.field(frozen=True)` before raising an error.